# How to access the application which is running on Docker swarm cluster?

Tags: docker-swarm

I am new to the Docker swarm. I deployed  a Jenkins service on Docker swarm cluster with 3 managers and 2 worker nodes. I can access the service using node port. But, I want to access the service from outside network using an external loadbalancer. If any one have any reference, please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You specified an external load balancer, so you would do something like:

1. deploy hashicorp consul as part of your app stack, or as a swarm service, to your swarm.
2. integrate your services with hashicorp consul so they publish their external ips and ports to it. The services would be setup with host mode networking rather than using dockers ingress networking.
3. integrate your external load balancer with consul so it can deliver traffic to the service.
4. point your external dns as your external load balancer.